# Why does my external hard drive stop responding?

Tags: memory, external-hard-drive

After using my hard drive for about 20 minutes depending on what I'm doing on the hard drive, it make a click sound once, then stops responding until I re insert it. What causes this and how can I fix it? The hard drive is 300GB, I've been using it for a year now. The HDD is connected by usb.

Comment: Does the external enclosure have its own power supply? How is it connected to the PC?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: bad sectors can cause clikcing sounds, and can make it appear as thought the drive has stopped responding. It is more like it is a skipping record try running chkdsk with the /r switch to check it for errors. this can take a while